# MySQL / Moodle - Replace value in one field with index of pipe-delimited text field

Tags: mysql, sql, moodle

I'm trying to extract survey questions and answers, using SQL, from a Moodle server located in a MySQL database. (Moodle Version 3.1.7 (Build: 20170710))

The `mdl_feedback_item` table the stores questions, while the answers are obtained via a join with the `mdl_feedback_value` table.

This is my current sql script:

`select 
fi.id, fi.name as fb_question, fi.presentation as answer_options, fv.value as answer`
`from mdl_feedback fb`
`left join mdl_feedback_item fi on fi.feedback=fb.id`
`left join mdl_feedback_value fv on fv.item=fi.id`

Which results in:

`id / fb_question  / answer_options         / answer`
`68 / Do you ...   / Agree|Neutral|Disagree / 3`
`69 / Are you...   / Yes|No|Maybe           / 1`
`70 / Which day... / Monday|Tuesday         / 2`
`(...)`

My objective is to check the 'answer' value, and replace it with the corresponding answer_option:
`id / fb_question  / answer_options         / answer`
`68 / Do you ...   / Agree|Neutral|Disagree / Disagree`
`69 / Are you...   / Yes|No|Maybe           / Yes`
`70 / Which day... / Monday|Tuesday         / Tuesday`

There isn't a fixed minimum/maximum number of alternatives per question, so I think I'd need check the answer 'value' and then match it with the appropriate position in the pipe-delimited answer_options column.

Does anyone have any experience doing this type of extraction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer.

So, I can basically find out how many answer alternatives I'll have for a specific Course, by using LENGTH:

`Max((LENGTH(fi.presentation) - LENGTH(REPLACE(fi.presentation, '|', '')))+1)  as max_num_options,`

Let's say the result is 5.

So I then use SUBSTRING_INDEX in a CASE statement, which will give me the values for each of the 5 alternatives.

`CASE`

`WHEN fv.value = 1 THEN
(IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fi.presentation, '|', ((LENGTH(fi.presentation) - LENGTH(REPLACE(fi.presentation, '|', '')))+1) ), '|', -1 ) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fi.presentation, '|', (((LENGTH(fi.presentation) - LENGTH(REPLACE(fi.presentation, '|', '')))+1)-1) ), '|', -1 ),"",SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(fi.presentation, '|', 1 ), '|', -1 )))`

`WHEN fv.value = 2 THEN
(IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fi.presentation, '|', ((LENGTH(fi.presentation) - LENGTH(REPLACE(fi.presentation, '|', '')))+1) ), '|', -1 ) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fi.presentation, '|', (((LENGTH(fi.presentation) - LENGTH(REPLACE(fi.presentation, '|', '')))+1)-1) ), '|', -1 ),"",SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(fi.presentation, '|', 2 ), '|', -1 )))`

`WHEN fv.value = 3 THEN
(IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fi.presentation, '|', ((LENGTH(fi.presentation) - LENGTH(REPLACE(fi.presentation, '|', '')))+1) ), '|', -1 ) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fi.presentation, '|', (((LENGTH(fi.presentation) - LENGTH(REPLACE(fi.presentation, '|', '')))+1)-1) ), '|', -1 ),"",SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(fi.presentation, '|', 3 ), '|', -1 )))`

`WHEN fv.value = 4 THEN
(IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fi.presentation, '|', ((LENGTH(fi.presentation) - LENGTH(REPLACE(fi.presentation, '|', '')))+1) ), '|', -1 ) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fi.presentation, '|', (((LENGTH(fi.presentation) - LENGTH(REPLACE(fi.presentation, '|', '')))+1)-1) ), '|', -1 ),"",SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(fi.presentation, '|', 4 ), '|', -1 )))`

`WHEN fv.value = 5 THEN
(IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fi.presentation, '|', ((LENGTH(fi.presentation) - LENGTH(REPLACE(fi.presentation, '|', '')))+1) ), '|', -1 ) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(fi.presentation, '|', (((LENGTH(fi.presentation) - LENGTH(REPLACE(fi.presentation, '|', '')))+1)-1) ), '|', -1 ),"",SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(fi.presentation, '|', 5 ), '|', -1 )))`

`ELSE 'No answer given / text field'`
`END AS fv_response_text`

It's a bit messy, and I'll always have to check how many alternatives there are beforehand, but it gets the job done.